# Abrir arquivo xlsx com muitas linhas com panda em Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

Boa tarde pessoal, sou novato em python e estava tentando abrir o arquivo 'scores.csv.xlsx' ele tem 1128001 linhas, porém da o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código está assim:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

scores = pd.read_excel('scores.csv.xlsx',nrows = 1000)
display(scores)
```

Como faz para ler um arquivo com esta quantidade de linhas?

Link para o arquivo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zxp42DHcm5bgP3nGA4uVSuxSVcqnREZGqL77ojLpp-E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: pode disponibilizar o arquivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o método read_csv, seu arquivo é um CSV justamente por conter muitas linhas e o excel não consegue trabalhar com esta quantidade.

Exclua a extensão ".xlsx" e trabalhe como um csv mesmo que é o seu original.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

scores = pd.read_csv('scores.csv')
display(scores)
```

Answer (score -5):

scores = pd.read_csv('scores.csv')
display(scores)